# Install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 keeping the recovery partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, that is already installed on my Dell notebook, but I want to preserve the recovery partition.

In the image you can see the situation of my hard disk at this moment, I would appreciate if someone can tell me the steps to install Ubuntu in the correct way in order to preserve the recovery partition and the Windows installation, in order to have a dual boot system.

See partition table below!

[image: partition table]

Comment: From within Windows shrink the size of C: from the 900+GB to a comfortable size. The newly created empty space would be used for Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Thank you @WinEunuuchs2Unix.
During the Ubuntu installation what I have to choose? 
1) "Install alongside" (so Ubuntu will detect the free space and deal with the partitioning automatically, right?) 
2) "Something else"

Comment: You have less than 4 partitions. What makes you think you'd have to delete the recovery partition to install Ubuntu?

Comment: @a.lepore4 I've always done the "Something else" first to create EXT4 and SWAP partitions manually but that is more complicated and sometimes I've had to redo it (especially my first time). Choosing the "alongside" option would be definitely easier. Read this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto My question is how to deal with the Ubuntu installation in order to leave the recovery partition fully functional

Comment: You simply install it. No partition will be deleted unless you explicitly tell Ubuntu to do so.